# Efficient way to merge conflicts with VS Team services and Git?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge, git-flow

I use Git Flow, Beyond Compare as my merge tool and Visual Studio Team Services as the repo.

I am currently "finishing a feature" via Git Flow which effectively means I am trying to merge the "feature branch" with the "develop branch". The "feature branch" has been going on for a little while so there is some newer code in the "develop branch", hence the merge conflicts. Currently via "git mergetool" I am working through the conflicts using "Beyond Compare". However I was struggling to know which code to take into the "develop branch", until I opened up a seperate VSTS browser window to show the commit history for the conflicting file, and then using this commit history, to then identify only the code that has changed within this feature. So I am using the VSTS commit history to tell me what to copy across. It seems very manual to me, and a little long winded. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Did you configure GUI mergetool editors https://gist.github.com/karenyyng/f19ff75c60f18b4b8149?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am, for the time being, sticking with the manual approach to conflict resolution, using VS as my editor and then adding/committing the files. This is the recommended approach apparently. When I get more skilled I will revisit the merge tools. I was using Tortoisemerge and Beyond compare both configured at different times in git bash.

Comment: Not clear about your issue, do you mean you can't resolve conflict through GUI mergetool editors?

Comment: No I use to use command line GIT Bash merge tools such as tortoisemerge. I think I have come to an answer. Basically I now use Visual Studio to handle the conflicted file which contains the <<<<HEAD and <<<Feature markings. When I resolve these and then add/commit the conflict is resolved. Apparently this is the manual and recommended route. Using Mergetools is not recommended in the first instance as they are more advanced.

Comment: >> I think I have come to an answer, you can make a conclude and give a answer, then mark it after 24 hour.

Comment: Could you make a conclusion and post an answer?